# Error when running mapreduce job in cloudera

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

Hi there when running a mapreduce job (CardDriver example) on my cluster (with CDH 5, hive, hdfs, Yarn, cloudera management services) got an error and here is the trace, Any advice is very much appreciated::

```
[10/Jul/2014 07:42:00 -0700] base         ERROR    Internal Server Error: /jobbrowser/jobs/job_1403859859091_0003/tasks/task_1403859859091_0003_r_000006/attempts/attempt_1403859859091_0003_r_000006_0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/apps/jobbrowser/src/jobbrowser/views.py", line 68, in decorate
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/apps/jobbrowser/src/jobbrowser/views.py", line 357, in single_task_attempt
    "task": task
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_util.py", line 222, in render
    **kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_util.py", line 144, in _render_to_response
    return django_mako.render_to_response(template, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_mako.py", line 117, in render_to_response
    return HttpResponse(render_to_string(template_name, data_dictionary), **kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_mako.py", line 106, in render_to_string_normal
    result = template.render(**data_dict)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/mako/template.py", line 443, in render
    return runtime._render(self, self.callable_, args, data)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 786, in _render
    **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 818, in _render_context
    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 844, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmplebzDl/jobbrowser/attempt.mako.py", line 198, in render_body
    __M_writer(escape(unicode( comps.get_container_link(status, attempt.nodeHttpAddress, attempt.taskTrackerId) )))
AttributeError: Attempt instance has no attribute 'nodeHttpAddress'

[10/Jul/2014 07:42:00 -0700] middleware   INFO     Processing exception: Attempt instance has no attribute 'nodeHttpAddress': Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Django-1.4.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 111, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/apps/jobbrowser/src/jobbrowser/views.py", line 68, in decorate
    return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/apps/jobbrowser/src/jobbrowser/views.py", line 357, in single_task_attempt
    "task": task
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_util.py", line 222, in render
    **kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_util.py", line 144, in _render_to_response
    return django_mako.render_to_response(template, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_mako.py", line 117, in render_to_response
    return HttpResponse(render_to_string(template_name, data_dictionary), **kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/desktop/core/src/desktop/lib/django_mako.py", line 106, in render_to_string_normal
    result = template.render(**data_dict)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/mako/template.py", line 443, in render
    return runtime._render(self, self.callable_, args, data)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 786, in _render
    **_kwargs_for_callable(callable_, data))
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 818, in _render_context
    _exec_template(inherit, lclcontext, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
  File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.2-1.cdh5.0.2.p0.13/lib/hue/build/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Mako-0.8.1-py2.7.egg/mako/runtime.py", line 844, in _exec_template
    callable_(context, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/tmplebzDl/jobbrowser/attempt.mako.py", line 198, in render_body
    __M_writer(escape(unicode( comps.get_container_link(status, attempt.nodeHttpAddress, attempt.taskTrackerId) )))
AttributeError: Attempt instance has no attribute 'nodeHttpAddress'
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the task is no running yet?

Similar to https://review.cloudera.org//r/4304/